# error: package javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: maven, servlet-filters

I was trying to implement a login filter in my web app with jsf 2, following this guide:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

after I compiled my filter and added the .class in "web-inf/classes" (as the guide says) the filter worked, but i put the  wrong url to redirect to the login page so i deleted the filter.class from the folder (web-inf/classes) and tried to compile the project again , but it failed, and since then im getting "package javax.servlet does not exist"

it is weird because before it was working and i have javax.servlet in my pom.xml.. i tried cleaning the project, but nothing.

this is my filter class:

```
package Bean;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: rodrigo
 * Date: 28-04-13
 * Time: 06:54 AM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
@WebFilter("/Contenido/*")
public class filtro implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // If you have any <init-param> in web.xml, then you could get them
        // here by config.getInitParameter("name") and assign it as field.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        LoginBean user = (LoginBean) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");

        if (user != null && user.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is logged in, so just continue request.
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // User is not logged in, so redirect to index.
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/Contenido/Login.xhtml");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // If you have assigned any expensive resources as field of
        // this Filter class, then you could clean/close them here.
    }
}
```

this is the error:

```
\Users\rodrigo\IdeaProjects\Frutemu\src\main\java\Bean\filtro.java:[5,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\rodrigo\IdeaProjects\Frutemu\src\main\java\Bean\filtro.java:[6,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\rodrigo\IdeaProjects\Frutemu\src\main\java\Bean\filtro.java:[7,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\rodrigo\IdeaProjects\Frutemu\src\main\java\Bean\filtro.java:[8,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\rodrigo\IdeaProjects\Frutemu\src\main\java\Bean\filtro.java:[9,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\rodrigo\IdeaProjects\Frutemu\src\main\java\Bean\filtro.java:[10,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\rodrigo\IdeaProjects\Frutemu\src\main\java\Bean\filtro.java:[11,31] error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
```

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Frutemu</groupId>
    <artifactId>Frutemu</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Frutemu Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-b10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1-b04</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OpenJPA framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Frutemu</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Open Jpa -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>**/model/*.class</includes>
                    <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                    <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhancer</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Plugin para levantar una instancia de Tomcat 7 liviana, única para este proyecto -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/Frutemu</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <!--note this must be repeated here to pick up correct xml validation -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please use a valid package name like in the example. Write "package com.example;" instead of " package Bean;". Furthermore I suggest with regards to the Java naming conventions to start your class name with a capital letter (Filtro instead of filtro). Do you still get the error message?

Comment: the package name is ok, it's is generated automathically in intellij when i create a new class inside of the folder "Bean", all my issues started after i compiled filtro.java and added the generated filtro.class in web-inf/classes, since i did that im getting this error.

Comment: Please see this link regarding the package naming conventions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: thanks for the link, i know there are conventions about package and class names , but that doesnt explain my problem.. before i did what expalin in my first  post everything was ok , so the problem is not related to the package name, i think something got messed up after i copied and deleted the filtro.class into web-inf/classes...

Comment: The error appears during the compile phase. Most likely the error is in your pom.xml. I can reproduce the error messages by commenting out the javax.servlet dependency in the pom.xml. If you are not sure about this please post your pom.xml.

Comment: i added the pom.xml :), anyway, i dont think it is the pom either.. i havent changed anything.. like i said before, i right clicked in "filtro.java" , then compile, look for the .class generated i copied it  in web-inf/classes, the login filter worked but my link for the login page was wrong, so i deleted it and tried to compile again then i started getting this error.. it doesnt make any sense :(!

Comment: Please try to add the dependency as I just suggested. It is unlikely that the error happened when you copied the class file as the error already occurs during the compilation of your source code.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The javax.servlet dependency is missing in your pom.xml. Add the following to the dependencies-Node:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have this one :

  <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

anyway, before i tried adding the one you are telling me and i got the same error.. now i added this one: 

 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

and it worked. aarggh, the weird thing is that it worked before without that.

thanks for your help

Comment: I added that dependency to my POM as-is, @Matthias, but I'm still getting the `missing symbol` errors for those classes. Any gotchas that I should know about?

Comment: @KevinMeredith did you find a solution? If not, can you please post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Be sure the servlet api version you use matches your application server.

Answer (score 7):

I only put this code in my pom.xml and  I executed the command maven install.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @Matthias Herlitzius is mostly correct. Just for further clarity.

The servlet-api jar is best left up to the server to manage [see here for detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595797/cant-import-javax-servlet-annotation-webservlet)

With that said, the dependency to add may vary according to your server/container. For example in Wildfly the dependency would be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So becareful to check how your container has provided the servlet implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to import javaee-api as well.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax</groupId>
     <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
     <version>7.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Unless I got following error:

```
package javax.servlet.http does not exist
javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
javax.servlet.http does not exist
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got here with a similar problem with my Gradle build and fixed it in a similar way:

```
Unable to load class hudson.model.User due to missing dependency javax/servlet/ServletException
```

fixed with:

```
dependencies {
   implementation('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, migrating a Spring 3.1 app up to 3.2.7, my solution was similar to Matthias's but a bit different -- thus why I'm documenting it here:

In my POM I found this dependency and changed it from 6.0 to 7.0:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then later in the POM I upgraded this plugin from 6.0 to 7.0:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    ...
                    <configuration>
                        ...
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when using IntelliJ IDEA despite having `javax.servlet-api` listed as a dependency in my `pom.xml` file.

Turns out my Java project did not have Maven framework support. Here is how I added it:

1. Right click on the project in Project View -> select 'Add Framework Support...'
2. Select 'Maven'
3. In the Maven View that shows up, click 'Download Sources and/or Documentation'

Hope this helps anyone new to IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score -6):

**maybe doesnt exists javaee-api-7.0.jar.**
download this jar and on your project right clik

1. on your project right click
2. build path
3. Configure build path
4. Add external Jars
5. javaee-api-7.0.jar choose
6. Apply and finish

Comment: Doesn't apply to a Maven project.

Comment: Not helpful to give IDE or code editor specific instructions, without even saying which editor you're referring to.