# The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp

I have a project created by Maven integration in Eclipse. All work fine, but in the work space in all JSP files have this:

```
The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path
```

To the first string where place:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

When I create a basic dynamic web project and JSP in - all is fine, no errors.

Comment: You need to add the library in the build path.  http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-dependency-libraries-not-deploy-in-eclipse-ide/

Comment: you might have missed the javax.servlet-api dependance in pom.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16263523/1225526

Comment: Be sure that you add it as `provided` dependency i.e. that it is not shipped with your web project.

Comment: better answer at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4076601/1851302

Comment: I'd like to know why things are shipped that don't work unless you google and read the answer on stack overflow! I know, job security for the volunteers, but wow I just installed STS, created a new maven project, and the error just showed up. Not just complaining here (well maybe a bit), but why do things end up like this a large portion of the time when concerning eclipse-built solutions? (not blaming eclipse specifically, just a correlation).

Comment: I had a similar issue, which was based on the way I opened the project. Needed to import as maven project instead... details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357109/maven-project-in-eclipse-org-springframework-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-from

Answer (score 695):

Add a runtime first and select project properties. Then check the server name from the 'Runtimes' tab as shown in the image.

[image: Select runtime from Project Facets as shown the in image]

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is working? How is the targeted runtime and a missing http-servlet connected? I'd be very interested in what's going on behind the curtains.

Comment: This error indicates that http-servlet is not available in the project class path, once we add target-runtime to the project , http-servlet will be available in  the project class-path.

Comment: I did not have the Tomcat option in Runtimes in my Eclipse Mars, solved this in Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add > Apache Tomcat > chose de installation directory > Install

Comment: this is so out dated. in most case you use maven tomcat6 or 7 plugin.

Comment: In a project without using Maven, you can clear this error by right click your project name in Eclipse Project Explorer -> Properties -> Java Build Path, and check Apache Tomcat server to add it to your Java Build Path.

Comment: If error still exists, select the project and press `ALT` + `F5` to update the project.

Comment: If someone is wondering where to find this window like I was.. It would appear when in 'Package Explorer' view > Right Click on your 'Project Folder' > select 'Properties'. On the Left panel, click on 'Project Facets'. There it is!

Comment: It worked for me but I also had to do a project clean + rebuild (*Project -> Clean*) to get rid of the problem.

Comment: I have tried this solution and my problem still exists. I configured a runtime for was 8.5.

Comment: did someone found a solution?, i checked Tomcat in runtimes but the problem still there.

Answer (score 264):

Include `servlet-api-3.1.jar` into your dependencies.

- **Maven**

  ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  ```
- **Gradle**

  ```groovy
    configurations {
        provided
    }
    sourceSets {
        main { compileClasspath += configurations.provided }
    }
    dependencies {
        provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    }
  ```

Comment: a better answer would be `Include servlet-api-x.y.jar in your dependencies.` I though 3.0 was the latest.

Comment: error was gone, but on another pc i don't need do this.

Comment: How is this other PC different?

Comment: Only by Eclipse version, Kepler - error, Juno - ok.

Comment: If you are using Maven to manage your dependencies and if the web container you deploy to (Tomcat?) doesn't differ, it should work. Do you deploy from inside Eclipse?

Comment: The Servlet API Version to be used is determined by the container. So you need to know which is the traget system. To avoid classpath problems don't ship the servlet api with our artifact thus mark the depency als 'provided' in your pom.

Comment: If you are using Maven, then it will solve the issue.

Comment: I wonder why people downvote my answer. A comment would be useful.

Comment: where can I find this file?

Comment: This answer is almost completely right. The issue: `<version>3.1</version>` does not exist: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api shows what version *do* exist. I suggest you edit your answer to `3.0.1`or `3.1.0` (I would edit it but edits must be 6+ characters in length)

Comment: `3.1.0` it shall be then.

Comment: Once you specify a target runtime such as tomcat, you don't need to explicitly include the javax.servlet-api.jar. It will find it in the tomcat installation folder.

Answer (score 119):

Project → *Properties* → *Target Runtimes* → *Apache Tomcat* worked for me. There is no Target Runtimes under Facets (I'm on [Eclipse v4.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Juno)).

Answer (score 66):

**For an Ant project**:

Make sure, you have servlet-api.jar in the `lib` folder.

**For a Maven project:**

Make sure, you have the dependency added in `POM.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Another way to do it is**: Update the project facets to pick up the right server.

Check this box in this location:

Project → *Properties* → *Target Runtimes* → Apache Tomcat (any server)

Comment: The second suggestion worked for me.  The project was created but the Tomcat server was not checked in "Target Runtimes".

Answer (score 29):

Project → *Properties* → *Target Runtimes* → *Apache Tomcat worked for me. There is no Target Runtimes under Facets (I'm on [Eclipse v4.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Luna)).

Answer (score 26):

**Adding the Tomcat server in the server runtime will do the job:**

*Project Properties* → *Target Runtimes* → Select your Server from the list, "JBoss Runtime" → <kbd>Finish</kbd>

In case of Apache you can select Apache Runtime.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

These steps can really help you:

1. If you didn't install any server you have to do these steps:

   Menu *Window* → *Preferences* → *Expend Server* → *Runtime environment* → *Add* → choose a name and then choose the Apache server path that you already installed on your PC (you can press download and install too) → <kbd>Finish</kbd> → <kbd>OK</kbd>

Ref# [for more information, click here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwtomprf.html)

2. Add the Tomcat server:

   *Project Properties* → *Java Build Path* → *Add Library* → Select "Server Runtime" from the list* → *Next* → Select "Apache Tomcat" → <kbd>Finish</kbd>

Ref# [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936848/the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 16):

Just add these dependencies to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why do we need the second dependency ? Please remove the second! (jsp-api).

Comment: no first one is enough.

Answer (score 14):

Adding the Tomcat server in the server runtime will do the job:

Project properties → *Java Build Path* → *Add Library* → *Select "Server Runtime"* from the list → *Next* → Select "Apache Tomcat" → *Finish*.

Answer (score 6):

Select project → *Properties* → *Project Facets* → *Target Runtimes* → *VMware Server*.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

As this is unanswered, I am guessing something other than Maven dependencies are wrong with the ops build.

While not using Maven, I have the same problem from time to time when re-creating my development environment from svn, and I always forget why and have to figure it out. Unfortunately it seems this is a problem with Eclipse.

I am able to remove all such errors from once working projects by picking just one of the dynamic web projects, or just tomcat dependent projects, and move a dependency in the build order. This seems to force all projects to rebuild properly and all of the errors are then resolved.

Right click on a web project, select "build Path" -> "Configure Build Path".
Go to the tab "Order and Export", then pick a library or jar entry and move it up or down. I used the JRE System Library and moved it to the top.

Click OK, and all that red goes away!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Maven, just drop the javax.servlet-api.jar in your project lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

**In case of JBoss...** right click on project → *Build Java path* → add external JAR files.

Then browse to jboss-folder → *Common* → *lib* → servlet-api.jar

.
.
Click <kbd>OK</kbd>, refresh the project, and run it...

Comment: Why is it only on Jboss ? Please remove that!

Answer (score 0):

And if nothing works by whatever reason, build it from the command line:

```
ant -Dj2ee.server.home=D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23 clean

ant -Dj2ee.server.home=D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23 compile

ant -Dj2ee.server.home=D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23 dist
```