# Maven Project in Eclipse `org.springframework cannot be resolved to a type` from target path

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, dependency-management

I've rolled onto a maven project that when I run `mvn clean install` from command line builds and runs fine. I had this project displaying in Eclipse without errors earlier in the week before I hosed my system. This makes me think I have a configuration wrong and hoping someone can give me a sanity check.

Inside of Eclipse, I'm seeing reported errors related to `org.springframework cannot be resolved to a type` in files in paths like `<project_path>/target/<project>-<version>/WEB-INF/...` What is catching my eye is that path of `target` which is a derived folder.

Maven Dependencies Showing:

[image]

Facets Enabled:

[image]

Project Explorer View:

[image]

From the above screenshots, you can see that the related jar files are pulled properly from the maven dependencies. Any ideas on what I have misconfigured and why I'm seeing the errors from the target path?

Comment: The `build` and `WebContent` folders indicates that you haven't properly imported maven project into eclipse. Delete project in eclipse, delete all folder beside `src`, import existing maven project into eclipse.

Comment: @AleksandrM If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it. Solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build` and `WebContent` folders indicate that you haven't properly imported Maven project into the Eclipse, hence errors.

One of the way to fix this:

- Delete project from the Eclipse.
- Go to project folder and delete all not needed folders. (Leave `src`).
- Go to Eclipse click `File` -> `Import...`, select `Existing Maven Projects`, select your project folder, `Finish`.