# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> generate in servlet mapping

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I followed this question solution [The superclass “javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet” was not found on the Java Build Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756153/the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build) and I get this exception when running Tomcat server:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/stpt-e]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/stpt-e]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> generate in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3254)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1430)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had create `generate.java` servlet but in that servlet I changed this code `@WebServlet("/generate")`  to `@WebServlet("generate")`.