# Maven can not find compiler

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I cannot compile the [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) project from the command line.
I am using Maven version :

[Apache Maven 3.5.4](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.4/release-notes.html)

This is my stack trace, what I am doing wrong here?

Error:

> - [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> - [WARNING]
> - [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for MONTANA:MONTANA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
> - [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 13,
>     column 21
> - [WARNING]
> - [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they    threaten the stability of your build.
> - [WARNING]
> - [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer    support building such malformed projects.
> - [WARNING]
> - [INFO]
> - [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------
> - [INFO] Building MONTANA 1.0-SNAPSHOT
> - [INFO] --------------------------------[jar]---------------------------------
> - [INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> - [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> - [INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> - [INFO] Total time: 0.183 s
> - [INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-17T10:34:57+03:00
> - [INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> - [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "inctall". You must specify a valid    lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or
>     :[:]:.
>     Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
>     generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
>     process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
>     process-test-sources, generate-test-resources,
>     process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test,
>     prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test,
>     post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean,
>     post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
> - [ERROR]
> - [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with    the -e switch.
> - [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug    logging.
> - [ERROR]
> - [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,    please read the following articles:
> - [ERROR] [Help 1]    http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
> - [WARNING] Some problems were

There is my pom.xml (without dependencies):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MONTANA</groupId>
<artifactId>MONTANA</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build
```

The new stack trace is:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [WARNING] [WARNING] Some problems were
>   encountered while building the effective model for
>   MONTANA:MONTANA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT [WARNING]
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 13,
>   column 21 [WARNING] [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these
>   problems because they threaten the stability of your build. [WARNING]
>   [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer
>   support building such malformed projects. [WARNING] [INFO] [INFO]
>   --------------------------< MONTANA:MONTANA >--------------------------- [INFO] Building MONTANA 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar
>   ]--------------------------------- [INFO] [INFO] ---
>   maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ MONTANA --- [INFO]
>   Deleting D:\Documents\Uni\Java\MONTANA\target [INFO] [INFO] ---
>   maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MONTANA ---
>   [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered
>   resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] Copying 0 resource
>   [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)
>   @ MONTANA --- [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
>   [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding
>   Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] Compiling 17 source
>   files to D:\Documents\Uni\Java\MONTANA\target\classes [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[9,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[10,32]
>   package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[11,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[12,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[13,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[20,35]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[19,2]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class WebServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[22,27]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[22,55]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[22,92]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[76,26]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[76,54]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[76,91]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[3,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[4,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[5,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[6,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[9,33]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[12,24]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[12,52]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[12,89]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[24,23]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[24,51]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[24,88]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[3,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[4,32]
>   package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[5,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[6,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[7,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[11,33]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[10,2]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class WebServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[12,27]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[12,55]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[12,92]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[16,26]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[16,54]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[16,91]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[3,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[4,32]
>   package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[5,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[6,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[7,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[11,34]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[10,2]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class WebServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[12,27]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[12,55]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[12,92]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[16,26]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[16,54]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[16,91]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[8,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[9,32]
>   package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[10,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[11,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[12,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[13,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[20,36]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[19,2]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class WebServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[21,27]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[21,55]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[21,92]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[55,26]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest   location:
>   class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[55,54]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse   location:
>   class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[55,91]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ServletException   location:
>   class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[11,5]
>   method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[23,5]
>   method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[44,13]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Cookie   location: class
>   Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[44,33]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Cookie   location: class
>   Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[57,9]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class Cookie   location: class
>   Actions.Authorization [INFO] 69 errors [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 10.092 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2018-08-17T12:11:19+03:00 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project MONTANA: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure: [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[9,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[10,32]
>   package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[11,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[12,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[13,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[20,35]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[19,2]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class WebServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[22,27]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[22,55]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[22,92]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[76,26]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[76,54]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Registration.java:[76,91]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Actions.Registration [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[3,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[4,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[5,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[6,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[9,33]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[12,24]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[12,52]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[12,89]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[24,23]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[24,51]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[24,88]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Pages.Registered [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[3,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[4,32]
>   package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[5,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[6,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[7,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[11,33]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[10,2]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class WebServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[12,27]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[12,55]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[12,92]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[16,26]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[16,54]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/PageOfUser.java:[16,91]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Pages.PageOfUser [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[3,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[4,32]
>   package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[5,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[6,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[7,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[11,34]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[10,2]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class WebServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[12,27]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[12,55]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[12,92]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[16,26]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[16,54]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/MessagePage.java:[16,91]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Pages.MessagePage [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[8,21]
>   package javax.servlet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[9,32]
>   package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[10,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[11,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[12,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[13,26]
>   package javax.servlet.http does not exist [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[20,36]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class HttpServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[19,2]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol: class WebServlet [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[21,27]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[21,55]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[21,92]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[55,26]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
>   [ERROR]   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[55,54]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
>   [ERROR]   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[55,91]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class ServletException [ERROR] 
>   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[11,5]
>   method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Pages/Registered.java:[23,5]
>   method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[44,13]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class Cookie [ERROR]
>   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[44,33]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class Cookie [ERROR]
>   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR]
>   /D:/Documents/Uni/Java/MONTANA/src/main/java/Actions/Authorization.java:[57,9]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class Cookie [ERROR]
>   location: class Actions.Authorization [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full
>   debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors
>   and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR]
>   [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: `inctall` is not a valid lifecycle... read the stacktrace. it even tells you all the valid ones

Comment: @GhostCat isn't `'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 13, column 21` just referring to the pom.xml and not to the maven installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mentioned in the comments you got a typo in Maven command, try

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: Are you getting the same stack trace after running as 'mvn clean install' ?

Comment: no, there is another stack trace. Should I open another question, or I can just update this question?

Comment: Could you post the new stack trace?

Comment: Yes, The new stack trace I'll put in this question.

Comment: you missing dependencies in the project that why you see the error messages like  package doesn't exist (eg: package javax.servlet does not exist)  Add the relevant dependencies required for the project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262948/error-package-javax-servlet-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> **First Solution** --> **please enter proper commands "*install*"*** Not "**inctall**"
>   According to your screen shot in the Question

Issue is not understandable  might you can find the exact issue by running mvn build life cycle commands

first step = `mvn validate`   **It will validate the pom.xml file and other dependency's**

Second Step = `mvn compile`  **It will compile and build the project**

Third Step = `mvn test`   **it will test all the basic cases**

Fourth step = `mvn package`    **It will give the jar/war/ear file**

Fifth step = `mvn verify`  **it will verify the build**

Sixth Step = `mvn install`  **It will build the project according to our pom**

Seventh step = `mvn deploy`   **The build will be deployed in specified tom cat server**

*Then you can find what is the error and where it has to be resolved at the specific situation (while running the mvn build life cycle commands )*